# Is there a way to catch the zoomed-out-max event in IE10 Metro?

Tags: javascript, c++, mobile, microsoft-metro, internet-explorer-10

In Internet Explorer 10 Metro Style I want to catch the event that happens when the user zooms out to full view using pinch gesture.

I can do it either using JavaScript running in the page or a C++ code running in IE address space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a hack but it's working, The extra minimum zoom is around 0.85 of the normal size so we check if the user zoomed out more than 0.87:

```
window.addEventListener ('resize', function () {
    if (document.documentElement.clientHeight / window.innerHeight <= 0.87){
        // this will run more than once while the user 
        // is zooming out close to the maximum level
    }
}, false);
```

It won't work when zooming is disabled (mobile websites).